# How do I install Google Chrome?

Tags: software-installation, web-browsers, chromium, midori

When I go to download Google Chrome from http://www.google.com/chrome in Midori on the Raspberry Pi , I am presented with a modal dialogue box,

> Please select your download package:
>
> - 32 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)
> - 64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)
> - 32 bit .rpm (For Fedora/openSUSE)
> - 64 bit .rpm (For Fedora/openSUSE)
>
> Not Debian/Ubuntu or Fedora/openSUSE? There may be a community-supported version for your distribution [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxChromiumPackages).

Is it possible to install Google Chrome on the Raspberry Pi?  How would I go about it?

Comment: Chromium binaries are [now available](http://hexxeh.net/?p=328117859).

Comment: I downloaded Noob today and it had Chromium installed built in.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can't install Google Chrome, but you can install Chromium.  As other people have posted, Chromium is the code base out of which Google Chrome is compiled.  Chromium is an open-source version of this browser.  Simply type the following.

#### Debian

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

If you receive any errors running this command, try running

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

and then rerun the first command again.

#### Arch

```
$ sudo pacman -S chromium
```

Comment: This "just worked".  Tested on Debian.  Shortcut appears in the "Internet" folder in the programs menu.

Comment: @McKAMEY sounds like the Raspbian people need to have a look at that so it can be integrated in the main repos.

Comment: what is the difference between `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` and `sudo apt-get install chromium`?

Comment: doesn't work on arch.

Comment: @Scoop "chromium-browser" is the old name for the package. Since Wheezy, it is a dummy package to install `chromium`. See http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=chromium

Comment: Anonymous user says: "If you going to install chromium I recommend doing it on the Raspberry Pi 2 B as the Pi 2 is powerful enough for it to be a smooth experience but if you going to do it on the Pi B+, B, A or A+ Overclock your Pi so it is more smooth but not as smooth as you what it to be."

Comment: Please Chromium does not support HTML5 video DRM and so cannot be used for netflix etc. Just use Chromium is not necessarily a solution for people.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for raspbian jessie - I get the message "E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate"

Comment: followed these instructions, and it worked like a charm - http://conoroneill.net/running-the-latest-chromium-45-on-debian-jessie-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/

Comment: It tells me "E: package 'chromium' has no installation candidate"

Comment: @Tass I am also receiving the no installation candidate error. Does this method no longer work?

Comment: As of today, this is not working on my Pi 3. I get the following error: Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  chromium-inspector chromium-bsu

Comment: `sudo apt-get install chromium` doesn't work anymore; you must use `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` instead.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know Google does not (yet) distribute Chrome binaries for Linux/ARM. (The only ARM binaries are for Android and these will not be compatible.)

You might be able to cross-compile [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers) for Linux/armel (I have not tried but I am willing to bet that the RasPi itself is not powerful enough to compile it.)

Also keep in mind that if you were able to install it, you may be disappointed with its performance as it is designed for somewhat more powerful machines.

Comment: I'm going to try X-compiling this evening. I shall let you know.

Comment: The Chromium available through apt-get is quite usable.  Note it does not support Youtube video.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is there any way to get video support for just mp4 or webm in chrome?

Comment: I do not know.  Note that the Chromium build is not the full Chrome browser as distributed by Google.  Given the amount of attention to the Pi I would say that you just need to wait a while longer.

Answer (score 12):

Note that `apt-get` gives you a [very old version of Chromium (v6)](http://www.engadget.com/2012/07/19/chromium-browser-for-raspberry-pi-beta-available/#comment-592970776). Hexxeh has a much newer build (v22):

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=11800
- http://hexxeh.net/?p=328117859

Comment: v22 Now installs from api-get and works well

Answer (score 6):

After finding out that Chromium is stuck at version 22 (current version is 31) I decided to switch to Firefox ie Iceweasel browser on Raspbian because it is kept updated.

Comment: As of February 2015, Chromium is still stuck at 22. Iceweasel is probably your best option.

Comment: If you have Raspberry Pi 2 and want latest version of Chromium you can update Raspbian from Wheezy (Debian 7.0) to Jessie (Debian 8.0) and then have all upto date packages, including Chromium and Iceweasel (Firefox).

Comment: How did you switch to Jessie (Debian 8)?

Comment: Alright found the answer [HERE](http://linuxconfig.org/raspbian-gnu-linux-upgrade-from-wheezy-to-raspbian-jessie-8)

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install iceweasel '

Answer (score 4):

Chromium is working fine and get reasonable performance on my Raspberry Pi. Better than [Midori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_%28web_browser%29).

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Comment: Chromium is really faster than Midori? Chrome was often a huge memory-hog that bogs down the system in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Open Source Chromium is really good alternative for Google Chrome. But sometimes it's needed original Google Chrome. For example, you can't watch video with Netflix or Amazon prime with Chromium because it lack a couple of libraries.

You can install original x86 Google Chrome with help of ExaGear Desktop.

1. Install ExaGear Desktop (note that ExaGear isn't free and you have to obtain the license)

   ```
   tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi2.tar.gz
   sudo ./install-exagear.sh
   ```
2. Run ExaGear Desktop

   ```
   exagear
   ```
3. Download Google Chrome

   ```
   wget http://mirror.retrosnub.co.uk/apt/google/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
   ```
4. Install Google Chrome

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
   ```
5. Now you can run Google Chrome from Start Menu

[image: Running Google Chrome on Raspberry Pi]

Based on [this post](https://eltechs.com/run-google-chrome-on-raspberry-pi/).

Answer (score 1):

This works great.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Comment: This doesn't work on RPi2 - Jessie

Answer (score 1):

Because the question is already answered, I will tell you something else.

If you dont use the new Pi2, I really recommend you using a different browser, like midori. Simply because things will run smoother in midori/every other lightweight browser that with chrome/-ium.

Comment: In fact if you don't use the new Pi2 you can no longer run a **recent** version of Chromium AT ALL - the older posts here refer to version 22 or so, and at the time of writing the current version is in the mid 40's - and does not IIRC have any GPU hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

#### Install Chromium on your Raspberry Pi with apt-get

At first, we have to update our packages. Open a terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, you can install it also by using the packet manager:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium --yes
```

Alternatively you can install the package chromium-browser instead of chromium.
That’s all! If you are connected through SSH or not using the graphical user interface, you should start (startx). Otherwise you can also establish a remote desktop connection. Now click the start button and navigate to “Internet” where you will find the Chromium shortcut.

---

## Install Chromium on Raspberry Pi’s by using git

If you want to compile the Raspberry Pi Chrome (Chromium) Browser yourself, visit their Google Source repository where you can also check the code. The code is not available on GitHub, but that makes no difference for cloning and compiling the repository. But you should know that the files to download are about 15 gigabyte (after installing in fact 22 GB). This is why I recommend the first option, if you only want to install it quickly. If the installation above failed (for any reason) or you want to inspect / change the code, this is how you can do it (you must have a Raspberry Pi Model 2B / 3, because the models before have not 4 kernels):
If you haven’t already installed git, you have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Next, we clone the whole repository to a specific folder, which we create and then go into this directory.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/chromium
cd /opt/chromium
sudo git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

Now you can check out the needed files (about 15 GB). Make sure that your micro SD card (32GB or more) has enough empty disk space.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/chromium/depot_tools
nice fetch --nohooks --no-history chromium
```

Depending on your internet speed this step can take a while. After finished downloading all files, you can compile the project.

```
./build/install-build-deps.sh
gclient runhooks
./build/gyp_chromium -Dcomponent=shared_library -Dfastbuild=1
nice ninja -C out/Release chrome
```

Based off [here](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/google-chrome-for-raspberry-pi/)

---

## Google Chrome installation instruction

***Note:*** **Exagear, which is needed is not free it does cost a few bucks for a license!**

## Configure Raspbian

1. **Google Chrome is CPU intensive application, therefore, we recommend to increase swap space. Open configuration file in Terminal (command line) using the following command:**

```
$ sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

Raspbian has 100MB of swap by default. You should change it to 2000MB in the configuration file. So you will have to find this line:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
```

And then change it into:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048
```

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> key to save changes and <kbd>F2</kbd> to close the file. Then restart dphys-swapfile to apply changes:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

## Install ExaGear Desktop

2. **Download ExaGear Desktop archive with installation packages and license key. Unpack the downloaded archive by entering the following command in Terminal:**

```
$ tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi3.tar.gz
```

3. **Install and activate ExaGear on your RPi by running install-exagear.sh script in a directory with deb packages and one license key:**

```
$ sudo ./install-exagear.sh
```

## Launch guest x86 system

4. **Enter the guest x86 system by using the following command:**

```
$ exagear
```

## Starting the shell in the guest image  `/opt/exagear/images/debian-8`

5. **Now you are in the x86 environment that can be checked by running the `arch` command:**

   ```
    $ arch
   i686
   ```
6. **It is recommended to update apt-get repositories on the first launch of the guest system:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

## Install Chrome

7. **Download Google Chrome:**

   ```
      $ wget http://mirror.retrosnub.co.uk/apt/google/pool/main/g/google- chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
   ```
8. **Install Chrome:**

   ```
     $ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
     $ sudo apt-get install -f
     $ sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```

## Run Chrome

Based off [here](https://eltechs.com/run-google-chrome-on-raspberry-pi/)