# Browsers for Raspbian soft-float

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers

I need Raspbian soft-float in order to use Java, and the bundled browsers are quite bad. Netsurf does not support JavaScript and Midori causes segmentation faults all the time. This Midori issue seems somewhat specific to the Pi, as I used the regular desktop versions a few times in the past, and it was a fine.

Chromium was my first bet, but unfortunately it seems to support only hardfp, for now. I need one with at least a basic JS support, and acceptable performance for the Pi, of course.

Which other browsers might I try?

Comment: I used to make this [PaleMoon build for armv6](https://www.palemoon.org/contributed-builds.shtml). It didn't have any success so I stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea if these are available on soft-float, just try to install them using atp-get:

```
dillo     (found nothing on JavaScript)
iceweasel (Should work with JavaScript, is Firefox in Debian style)
netsurf   (JavaScript support just started)
midori    (No idea about JavaScript support)
```

If something gets installed, you'll know it supports soft-float.

But you already tried the 'most likely', so I guess you're out of luck for the moment.

There is however a [thread on this site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-do-i-install-google-chrome) about Chromium, it has a link to compiling it yourself, but I guess that will keep your RPi busy for a very long time. The link also explains how to cross-compile it on your regular system.

But in general, I think the RPi is a little under powered to todays big  browsers, my experience with the one time I used soft-float is that it is much slower (in general) then HF. So I am afraid it will not be a nice experience to use these big browsers anyway.