# chrome store says my version of is not supported

Tags: chromium

Chrome store says my version of is not supported, directs me to update Chrome.
Tried apt-get update and then rebooting.
Is an updated package I am not aware of?

Comment: I get an error as well when I try to login with my google account with the Chromium in Raspbian. It says I have too old a version. I'm pretty sure your issue is the same with it being an old version. I see in another question (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-do-i-install-google-chrome) that you can upgrade the OS and get more current or change browsers.