# Better way to automatize task on WhatsApp Web over Raspberry Pi

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium

I want to automatize some tasks on WhatsApp Web using Python and Selenium over my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and I'm having difficulties to find a web browser that's compatible with all these requirements.

- I tried Chromium but WhatsApp Web doesn't work and the page directs to other modern browsers ([I tried this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100645/whatsapp-web-is-asking-to-update-chrome-while-using-chromium));
- I tried Firefox, but geckodriver (the webdriver of Firefox) does not  have an updated [Arm7 driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0) (most recent is V 0.23 and does not work on the most recent Firefox    version required by WhatsApp Web);
- And    finally [I read about Chrome](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-do-i-install-google-chrome), which is not compatible
  with    Raspberry Pi.

I am lost and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have WhatsApp Web working on Rasp Pi. I use Chromium and the ChromiumDriver.

First install the Chromium Browser and WebDriver. Copy the below in your Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Here is my Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
    
    
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data") #this is needed to stop WhatsApp asking for QR code verification after your first time
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='REMOVED']").click() #change Removed to the number of group you are sending a message to
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys('MESSAGE HERE')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button/span').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

I have only found one error and forward slashes will not send. Here is my [Stack Overflow post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824202/chromium-whatsapp-web-is-removing-forward-slashes-when-submitting-text-through-p). I found your post while trying to resolve my error.

Please note I am on a Raspberry 4 and I'm not 100% sure if it will work on Raspberry 3.